# ARSession and Recording Video

Tags: ios, avfoundation, video-processing, arkit

I’m manually writing a video recorder. Unfortunately it’s necessary if you want to record video and use ARKit at the same time. I’ve got most of it figured out, but now I need to optimize it a bit because my phone gets pretty hot running ARKit, Vision and this recorder all at once.

To make the recorder, you need to use an `AVAssetWriter` with an `AVAssetWriterInput` (and `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor`). The input has a `isReadyForMoreMediaData` property you need to check before you can write another frame. I’m recording in real-time (or as close to as possible).

Right now, when `ARKit.ARSession` gives me a new session I immediately pass it to the `AVAssetWriterInput`. What I want to do is add it to a queue, and have loop check to see if there’s samples available to write. For the life of me I can’t figure out how to do that efficiently.

I want to just run a while loop like this, but it seems like it would be a bad idea:

```
func startSession() {
    // …
    while isRunning {
        guard !pixelBuffers.isEmpty && writerInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData else {
            continue
        }
        // process sample
    } 
}
```

Can I run this a separate thread from the `ARSession.delegateQueue`? I don't want to run into issues with `CVPixelBuffer`s from the camera being retained for too long.

Comment: did you ever figure out what to do here?  I have this same use case and am looking for some orientation info.